# Why has onclick handler attached to a div stopped firing?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

We have some old code that has been running at a customer site for 5 years that includes a web solution where the user can bring up a set of images and when they click on one, a function is called that displays the image full size.

The customer has just migrated the virtual servers to a new environment, but the servers themselves should be identical and the code hasn't changed.

However, when they click on the thumbnail now, nothing happens. It works on my local system, and when I inspect the element, IE shows me the click handler in the "Events" window, but on the customer machine, no event is shown in the "Events" window, even though I can see it in the code.

I am running exactly the same code on both systems, but the versions of IE are different: 
11.0.9600.19374 on the one that doesn't work
11.504.17763.0 on the one that does

This has previously been working on IE8.

I've included just the HTML for a single div:

```
<div class="isotope_exhibit scene-0 isotope-item" id="image_3928" style="left: 143px; top: 0px; position: absolute;" onclick="openImageDetailsX(3928,1);" data-filter="" imgid="3928">

    <div style="width: 100%; height: 16px; display: inline; position: inherit;">

        <div id="image_rotate_left_3928" style="right: 4px; float: right; display: inline-block; position: inherit;">
            <span title="Rotate" class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w image_rotate_tag_3928" style="cursor: pointer;"></span>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="image_num_3928" style="left: 6px; top: 0px; color: rgb(93, 155, 217); font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; float: left; position: absolute;">D3: Image 2</div>

    <a title="DSC_8691" onclick="return false;" href="#">
        <div class="ui-state-default image_div_id_3928" style="background: none !important; position: relative; cursor: pointer;">

            <img class="lazy image_bg_id_3928 scene-0-image" id="img_thumb_3928" src="/includes/tn/3928">

        </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

It is the "openImageDetailsX()" function that is not getting called...

Comment: Sounds like an IE error, as much as you probably hate to hear it. What browser were you using to test? Just IE 8?

Comment: One thing that comes into mind is that some script before that function of yours failed to parse/execute, causing everything after it to not be present on the page. Also check for 404s, url paths, mixed content errors (i.e. loading HTTPS content in HTTP or vice versa). Content blockers are also notorious for suddenly failing pages. Check for ad blocking plugins, toolbars that hijack content, network-level blockers and firewalls, etc.

Comment: My suggestion is that: First, check if there is a blocker preventing the full-size image to pop up. Second, use the F12 tools to see if there's any error. Third, it seems the customer is using the older version of IE11, so update the IE11 to the latest version and try it again. You can also provide the relevant js code for us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. To answer a few of the questions:

The customer's machine previously had IE8 and it worked, now it has IE11 (11.0) and it doesn't. I am testing on my own system with the same versions of Apache server serving the website and PHP, using IE11.5 and it also works.

I've checked for errors in the Dev tools and can't see any. This is where I can see the onclick event on my system but not on the customer's.

They are not running any ad blockers or such like.

I can not update their servers but can ask their IT to do it.